# C binary message over amqp

Tags: c, binary, operating-system, rabbitmq, message-queue

Currently I have a daemon listening for TCP/UDP packets on port X using the `recvfrom` system call:

```
ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
             struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

and then the data is send over a message queue with the `msgsnd` system call:

```
int msgsnd(int msqid, struct msgbuf *msgp, int msgsz, int msgflg);
```

I would like to replace the `msgsnd` system call with RabbitMQ and send the messages using `amqp` protocol. The problem I am facing is the format of the data received and send over the RabbitMQ. When I receive data on port then I try to send it like this:

```
ssize_t recvfrom(
    sockfd, msgbufInst.msgContent, len, flags, src_addr, addrlen
);
send_over_rabbitmq(msgbufInst.msgContent);
```

where send_over_rabbitmq is pretty much

```
send_over_rabbitmq(char *rawData){
    amqp_bytes_t payload;
    payload.len = sizeof(rawData);
    payload.bytes = rawData;

    int result = amqp_basic_publish((*channel)->conn, 1, 
                 amqp_cstring_bytes("myExchange"),
                 amqp_cstring_bytes(""), 0, 0, NULL, payload);
}
```

The payload is send and received successfully but some data is lose. When I consume the message from the queue the payload is not the same as when I used the system call to send/consume messages. I am sure that it has to do with the data types that I am using but can't figure it out yet.

Comment: `sizeof(rawData)` is probably 8, maybe only 4 — it's the size of the pointer variable, and not the length of the data that it points at.  That probably isn't what you want.  You'll need to send more information to the `send_over_rabbitmq()` function — most noticeably, the length of the data received from `recvfrom()`.  That means capturing the information — you should be checking the return value from `recvfrom()` anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56912415/c-binary-message-over-amqp#comment100368332_56912415):

In the `send_over_rabbitmq()` function, the value of `sizeof(rawData)` is probably 8, and maybe only 4 — it's the size of the pointer variable, and not the length of the data that it points at. That probably isn't what you want.

You'll need to send more information to the `send_over_rabbitmq()` function — most noticeably, the length of the data received from `recvfrom()`. That means capturing the information — you should be checking the return value from `recvfrom()` anyway before trying to relay information via RabbitMQ.

Comment: You are right. When I consume the message from rabbitmqadmin I can see that all of the messages are 8 bytes. Do you think that I may be missing something else.

Comment: That's the primary item missing.  I don't immediately see anything else to cause trouble, but I've not written any RabbitMQ code so I'm not familiar with the `amqp_bytes_t` structure or the `amqp_basic_publish()` function and therefore don't know whether there are non-obvious subtleties in other fields in the structure or the zero and null arguments to the function.

Comment: I think it was the only issue. I am able to send the data even though the lib transforms it into base64. Thanks :)